# Mosfet Driver IRS2007 failure when running with mosfet IRFB3607

Tags: mosfet, brushless-dc-motor, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

I am designing a BLDC motor controller and facing some issues with using an IRS2007 along with IRFB3607.

[image]

For one phase, the high side and low side give clean wave forms as long as V_Pow is disconnected. 
Rise time - 300ns; Fall time-100 ns; On time - 312us; Period- 416us;

Once V_pow is connected, the input signal to the low side of the mosfet driver leaks to the high side and drives the gate of the high side mosfet. The gate of the low side mosfet is off.

This creates a high to high short over 2 phases of the motor and the motor immediately stops. This happened first time after running for about 1 min. Ever since, the motor does not run when powered by 3 phases.

The motor is a 48V 900W motor driven at 12V, no load (1A).

If driven by the two other phases, the motor runs.

------------------------End of current issue-----------------------------

Background:--------------------------

I have tried this configuration multiple times, at first I used a complimentary BJT (PNP_NPN) duo to increase the current pumped to the gate of the MOSFET

[image]

In this case the driver would work properly when V_POW was not connected but fail after V_POW was connected to 12 Volts.

Each time, with 3 phases and V_pow disconnected, the gate pulses would be in order. Once V_pow was connected, one phase would randomly fail before 1 cycle was completed.

After that the remaining 2 phases would happily power the motor till the failed Mosfet driver was replaced and then again within 1 cycle 1 phase would randomly fail.

In the above config, on mosfet driver failure, both HO and LO pins would be shorted with pins of V_Boost & V_in respectively. I presumed it was an internal MOSFET failure due to over current.

As of now I have destroyed 17 drivers trying to figure out what happened. Don't know what I am doing wrong, The power mosfets mosfets don't seem to fail. Max current through the power circuit is hardly 1 -2 amps.

[image]
[image]

The oscilloscope images are made into a powerpoint presentation which can be downloaded from https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nlpuCNPgn9C2LMH-RJehQwbQ5_Q2hv2O

Original circuit
[image]

Comment: Do you know what decoupling capacitors are? Or deadtime? Or flyback diodes?

Comment: Flyback diodes are built into the mosfets (I checked). Deadtime of 500ns  is built into the mosfet driver. The 1nF capacitors are meant to short HF pulses to ground. I think thats what you mean by decoupling capacitors.

Comment: No, C7/C8 is not what I am talking about Look up decoupling capacitors. Are you aware the LO side needs to turn on periodically to refresh to bootstrap cap so cannot run at 100% duty cycle? Or too low frequency at too high a duty cycle?

Comment: I would also scope your between VS-LO and between VB-HO and see if you are getting any ringing or spikes. I suspect C7/C8 are not doing you any good. They are significant relative to your gate-source capacitance. Scope it on your first circuit too. It was not clear in your post which one you were using.

Comment: I edited the question a bit to make it more understandable. I think this will help. Also I had missed a few more caps in the schematic somehow... Added them now. I'll upload the waveforms in a few hours once I reach office. In the off condition, all waves are clean but when powered on, it doesn't stay on for long enough to test anything.

Comment: _"This happened first time after running for about 1 min. Ever since, the motor does not run when powered by 3 phases. "_ - this suggests that something in that phase is blown up. You should test it with a current-limited power supply and small low current motor (eg. CDROM drive motor, low Kv 'drone' motor). Your PCB layout does not look good. Are you still using it? If so then perhaps you should design a new one without the unused parts and with better ground distribution.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Can you please explain a bit more about what is wrong with the PCB layout? Failure- 1 phase motor driver has a low side signal leaked to high side. I'd like to know why. There is no damage to Mosfet.

Comment: The track from driver pin 4 to ground is quite long and narrow. It should be as close as possible to the low-side FET Source. The PCB doesn't match your latest circuit and and haven't you shown us how you modified it, so I don't know what else might be wrong. Can you show us a photo of it? Not sure what you mean by 'leaking', but the FET does have significant capacitance which will transfer some of the Gate signal to the Drain. This is normal. Perhaps you could show us some waveforms? What part number are the diodes?

Comment: I edited the original schematic to make it more compact and easier for reading in the forum. The original schematic is uploaded in the question. I understand the COM and Source distance. I'll have to add a via to fix this.

Comment: 1 nF on the output. How come? Looks to me like insufficient decoupling combined with challenging layout, not that bad but not good either. Anyhow, you need oscillograms of every pin on your gate driver to tell.

Comment: You'll have to download the oscilloscope waveforms from the link in the question. Too many pictures to upload here. 1nF is intended as a high frequency noise bypass to source. There are decoupling capacitors for the V_in line....... Why would I add a decoupling capacitor on the gate and increase the switching time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem's solved. I needed to add a capacitance between V_pow and Ground on each of the 3 phases.

Since I was mostly working on low currents, I hadn't added an input capacitor or considered the length of the wire from the battery to the boards. Supposedly due to the wire inductance, when the high side mosfet turned off, there was a short, sharp voltage spike on the V_pow line.

That is why the motor would run with 2 phases as there were only 2 current carrying switching actions per cycle. When 3 phases were activated, I speculate that one mosfet would turn on during the V_pow peak and maybe damage the gate driver due to dV/dt or something.

Comment: This is what I was about to answer ;) For your  20A motor you need enough ceramic caps and a good amount of low ESR electrolytic caps to take that ripple current and ensure V_pow has low inductance to prevent voltage spikes. Note that if the motor is spinning and you lower the PWM value, motor will act as a brake and a generator, which will feed power back into the power supply. This is fine on batteries, but can be a problem on mains-powered supply.

Comment: Ceramic Caps and Low ESR Electrolytic caps where? Do I need to add any more? I am aware of regeneration...but does a motor regenerate if Duty cycle is reduced from 80% to 10%  ? I think it will just slow down due to load.

Comment: If the PWM slows down faster than motor rotation then the motor will act as a generator... The role of decoupling caps on your power supply voltage rail is not to absorb energy generated by the motor during braking (caps won't be enough for that) but to provide a local low inductance power supply whose voltage won't spike up or down when FETs turn on/off causing large di/dt current. If "L" is the inductance of your power supply and di/dt is your current switching speed, remember e=L*di/dt will be the height of the voltage spike...

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely overloading the gate driver with the gate current at turn-off. Try removing the diodes D_RX_GATES and try again. If that helps, do a redesign with a turn-off resistor in series with the diode.

When turning on the transistor, the gate current is limited by V/R_G, when turning off, the gate current is limited by V/R_diode, where R_diode is the equivalent resistance of the diode (very low, that's why you need an additional resistor). That's pretty well covered in any basic application note regarding gate driver design, for instance: AN2015-06 from Infineon, take a look at fig. 8.

[AN2015-06 from Infineon](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-EiceDRIVER-Gate_resistor_for_power_devices-ApplicationNotes-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462518ffd8501523ee694b74f18)

Comment: The issue is that it works properly when V_pow is not connected. So there is something in the transients that is messing up the mosfet driver.

Comment: When V_pow is not connected you don't have a discharge through the Miller capacitance and the D_RX_GATE diode

Comment: WOW! Finally a new point of view. Thanks and let me look into it.....
Regarding the Gate Diode, the On current of the Driver is 260mA and Off current is 600mA. I remember reading that having a resistor with a diode in parallel ensures that the turn off is faster than the turn on. Can you please explain a bit more on why the diode may be a problem?.................Also can you take a look at the waveforms?

Comment: I edited my answer to answer that